# BeautifulSoup "fixes" html on Windows 8, but not OS X or Windows 7

Tags: python, html, macos, windows-8, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup is giving me different results on different platforms. Can anyone help me understand why?

Create a `test.txt` file with the following contents:

```
<S1>
</S1>
```

When I run the following snipppet

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(lines)
print soup
```

On Windows 7 and on Mac OS X, it gives the result:

```
<S1>
</S1>
```

But on Windows 8, it changes it into a HTML document:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<S1>
</S1>
</body></html>
```

I know that BeautifulSoup will attempt to fix malformed HTML, but why are the results different here? Why doesn't it always fix it?

Note that on all 3 platforms the same versions of Python and BeautifulSoup were used (2.7.5 and 4.1.3).

Comment: however it works as expected for me on windows 7 on bs4 '4.3.1' and python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautifulsoup always uses the best available parser you have installed. I believe you have a different parser installed at your windows 8 compare to your other  two OS.

From the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

*If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.*

Comment: Indeed, after installing `html5lib` on OS X, my system now defaults to that parser (and it adds the tags), and I was able to reproduce the differences. Previously, I was under the assumption that if you don't specify anything, it always defaults to `html.parser`. Thanks!